# WooCommerce changes order status from Pending to On hold when customer orders the product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When customer orders the product order status is not Pending payment, but On hold.
In order window there is written something like that:

> We are waiting for transaction. Order status changed from Pending payment to On hold.

How can I prevent WooCommerce from changing status automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cod_process_payment_order_status', 'filter_process_payment_order_status', 10, 2 );
function filter_process_payment_order_status( $status, $order ) {
    return 'on-hold';
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).